# React Native TextInput auto Blur and hides keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-textinput

I'm building a generic form that fetches data from the server. Like a google forms clone.  In the FlatList when I scroll to the bottom the last TextInput element automatically hides the keyboard.

[image]

```
      <TextInput
        onBlur={() => console.log('I blur')}
        placeholder={title}
        onChangeText={text => setValue(text))}
        keyboardType="decimal-pad"
      />
```

I tried using KeyboardAvoiding and also KeyboardAwareFlatList but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `removeClippedSubviews` to `false` on the `FlatList`.

```
<FlatList
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
/>
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#removeclippedsubviews

It worked for my similar use case.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33642243)